# Asking admin rights c++ windows

Tags: c++, permissions, admin

Im very new in C++

I have found this post `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163486.aspx` and trying to ask admin right to windows.

I have created .manifest file added this

```
#define MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID 1
MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID RT_MANIFEST "MyAPP.exe.manifest"
```

To my main.cpp under #includes

visual studio says: `expected a declaration.`

What i am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it states in the link you provided:

> The following lines in the **.rc file** would embed the manifest above if
>   it were saved as Ad­min­App.exe.man­ifest:

```
#define MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID 1
MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID RT_MANIFEST "AdminApp.exe.manifest"
```

Your C++ project needs a resource file, and these lines belong in the .rc file, not your main.cpp

Don't forget to create your manifest file too.

Comment: I Have created .rc file and pasted it but i have same problem does this include is wright ? #include "MainHeader.rc"

Comment: @user525717 No you don't include MainHeader.rc, the resource file just defines things that get bundled with the code.  Its not code, it can't be compiled as code.